# How to save User ID after CloudKit record saved

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have had lots of initial success saving and querying records in CloudKit.  Now I am stuck on something easy.  For each user, I want to save his CloudKit user ID so they can view a list of their saved records.

I thought that the completionHandler provided the saved record, populated with useful meta info.  This is the start of my completionHandler func:

```
func recordSaved(record: CKRecord?, error: NSError?) {

        if (record != nil) {
            var myUserRecordID:CKRecordID = record!.creatorUserRecordID
            let UserRecordIDToStore = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(myUserRecordID)
            plist.setValue(UserRecordIDToStore, forKey: "lastCKRecordID")
        }
```

It is called when this save action is finished:

```
publicDatabase.saveRecord(newRecord, completionHandler: recordSaved)
```

However, in the first line after the if (starting with "var ...") I received the following error message: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  I don't understand why this is nil.

Please help:
1. Explain what I am doing wrong
2. Any tips on saving the user ID for future query use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  Here is the answer (just use it as stand alone code):

```
CKContainer.defaultContainer().fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler({ userRecordID, error in
            if error == nil {
                let UserRecordIDToStore = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(userRecordID)
                plist.setValue(UserRecordIDToStore, forKey: "userCKRecordID")
                println("User identified as: \(userRecordID.description)")
            } else {
                println("Can not identify user due to error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
```